# adBannerView in UIScrollView possible?

Tags: uiscrollview, iad, adbannerview

My `adBannerView`doesn't appear in my `UIScrollView`.

I suppose it is because user doesn't visualize the ad if he does not scroll. So Apple does not allowed it.

Is it right ? I have not found anything on the subject on the web.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place an `ADBannerView` inside an `UIScrollView` such as a `UITableViewController`

You can however use a `UIViewController` and add, on top of this view, an `ADBannerView` and `UIScrollView`.